# SubSonic SubSonic.SqlQuery & Dates

Tags: subsonic, date

Does SubSonic.SqlQuery have a between/and for date ranges?  If not, what would be the best way to get a range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SqlQuery query = new SqlQuery().From("Table")
                               .WhereExpression("Column")
                               .IsBetweenAnd("1/1/2008", "12/31/2008");
DataSet dataSet = query.ExecuteDataSet();  // Or whatever output you need
```

Comment: Here's another snippet.. which ended up being my solution..
.And(Order.OrderDateColumn).IsBetweenAnd(lastRunDate,System.DateTime.Now);

Answer (score 2):

Another way to query with SubSonic.

`TableCollection data = new TableCollection();`

```
Query q = Table.CreateQuery()
        .BETWEEN_AND("Column", "1/1/2008", "12/31/2008");

 data.LoadAndCloseReader(q.ExecuteReader());

// loop through collection
```

Answer (score 0):

Combined Northwind answer:

```
        SqlQuery query = new SqlQuery().From("Orders")
                                                             .WhereExpression("OrderDate")
                                                             .IsBetweenAnd("1996-07-02", "1996-07-08");
        DataSet dataSet = query.ExecuteDataSet();  // Or whatever output you need

        #region PresentResultsReplaceResponseWriteWithConsole.WriteLineForConsoleApp

        DataTable dt = dataSet.Tables[0];
        Response.Write("<table>");
        foreach ( DataRow dr in dt.Rows ) 
        {
            Response.Write("<tr>");
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    Response.Write("<td>");
                    Response.Write(dr[i].ToString() + " ");
                    Response.Write("<td>");
                } //eof for 
                Response.Write("</br>");
                Response.Write("</tr>");


        }
        Response.Write("<table>");
        #endregion PresentResultsReplaceResponseWriteWithConsole.WriteLineForConsoleApp
```